# GIS data for Grocery store sales in the US

Tags: data, united-states, business

I am looking for sources that would provide sales data for grocery stores in the US. I have looked at ESRI's Business Data that they receive from InfoGroup, but was wondering if anyone know of any other sources.

Comment: You might want to post your question here since it is related about finding the data... http://opendata.stackexchange.com/